# how to pick up the gridview cell value to use in if statement within for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, asp-classic

I have a gridview as shown bellow. I want to loop through it and count all the instances where gender is set to male using a for loop but I don't know how to pick up the value in the Gender cell to check if it's equal to "M".

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CourseCode,ClientNumber" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="237px" Width="801px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseCode" HeaderText="CourseCode" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CourseCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientNumber" HeaderText="ClientNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ClientNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" SortExpression="Forename" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: i did but my post was deleted. intellisense doesn't accept GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value and GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text didn't seem to count where the text in the cell was actaually 'M'. in the end i used GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Contains('M') and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each cell :

```
foreach(GridViewRow gridRow in myGridview.Rows)
{

        if(gridRow.Cells[6].Value=="M")
        {
          //Perform action
        }

}
```